# Some Finder Sidebar Icons Missing?

Tags: macos, icon

In the Finder windows, the iCloud Drive and Downloads icons are missing from my sidebar. I use CleanMyMac 2 could that have deleted the icons by mistake?

I have rebooted the icons are still gone.
![This is what it looks like.][1]

Yosemite 10.10.2 MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Mid 2014)

How can I get these icons back? Any idea what caused them to go away in the first place?

**Update:**

Can't I just drag the iCloud Drive icon into the info panel and change the icon like that? If so where can I find the original icon from?

Comment: did you reset your finder? use alt+cmd+esc than select Finder relaunch. And get rid off the CleanmyMac.

Comment: Ya I've done that many times I'm really not sure what to do.

Comment: We do not know what you have done already, so to spare us time please list it in your question.

Answer (score 1):

This generally happens when you've used a utility that changes your sidebar icons to colorized versions. iCloud Drive and Downloads do not use the standard icon format. These products are based on a SIMBL plugin called ColorfulSidebar that does not recognize the non-standard format. Even if you've changed the icons back to the non-colorized versions, the routine that changes the icons may still be running. You have to totally disable the software that colorized the icons.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like that you've used incompatible version of CleanMyMac 2. Please contact us for further instructions: support@macpaw.com

Regards,
MacPaw Support.

Comment: In its current form, this really only provides a reason, but not a fix. Please edit the answer to include a solution for the OP.

Comment: Fix would be good - there have been a few of these issues posted, none with any solution as yet.

Comment: This isn't delete worthy since it does in effect say you need the vendor's support to craft a specific solution. Better would be if they could link to an article or explain what version is compatible and/or if there are documented requirements or self help that could be edited into this post.