# Items vanished from Finder sidebar

Tags: finder, settings, ui

macOS 14.3.1 (23D60) & Finder 14.3

Earlier today, most of the icons vanished from my Finder sidebar.  I did not change any settings, and in fact, they are still selected to be there:
[image]

I do not use “[CleanMyMac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/178323/some-finder-sidebar-icons-missing)” or anything similar.  (I did use [Onyx](https://titanium-software.fr/en/onyx.html), but that was a long time ago.)  Turning some of those items off and back on did not help.  Rebooting did not bring them back.  Everything I've done today I've done almost every day for months without this happening.

**Reason?  How to fix?**

Comment: If you hover your pointer over Favorites, a right pointing arrow should appear to the very right of sidebar.  Click it to expand it again.

Comment: Aha!  Probably I accidentally clicked it.